# How do I create a rule to run during every cron run?

Tags: rules, social-network

I'm creating rules for posting to twitter. However I need these rules to run every time cron runs. What is the best way to structure these rules so they send the appropriate post at the appropriate time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) has a specific "React on event" under system -> "cron maintenance tasks performed". If your using the rules modules, that will trigger your rule on every cron run.

Also, if your building a custom module, and you need to call a function on every cron run, you can use [hook_cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) to add a function to the cron tasks as well.

Comment: Thanks, that helps start the rule, now how do I get it to choose a random piece of content based on certain conditions like the value of a taxonomy field?

Comment: After you've created a rule, there should be a conditions area where you can add conditions that, if meet, will allow the action to be triggered.

Comment: I see, cause I'm wanting that reaction to be if that fields equals a specific thing it would do something, but if it doesn't it would do another. an if rule.